# Unity3D Player Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do my player movement script in C# and for some reason, when I launch the game in unity it still doesn't work. I was wondering if after setting up the vectors in the script, if I need to say what button can be pressed to make the player move.

Here's my code that I have. (can't Post Pictures Currently)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void fixedupdate()
    {
        float movementHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float movementVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (movementHorizontal, 0.0f, movementVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT post pictures of your code.

Comment: 1: Have you attached the script to the player? 2: Make sure what buttons are bound to the axises. 3: Make some printouts to debug your code to see where you reach and what values you have

Comment: Also make sure that you have a RididBody associated with your gameobject.

Comment: Check that your speed is not set to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is case sensitive so if this is your exact code your functions will never be called. They need to be called `Start()` and `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Thank you that made the trick for me. Didn't know that they were case sensitive haha = )

Comment: @MrDucky38 assume all programming languages are case sensitive. Very few are not.

Answer (score 3):

You have named your methods incorrectly; The case matters. Because of this, they never get called. Instead they should be:

```
void Start()
```

and

```
void FixedUpdate()
```

Unity doesn't throw any errors because it thinks what you've written are your own private methods.